# Gluon Mobile (JavaFX): Failed Controller ClassNotFoundException

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluonfx

I'm trying to create a Gluon example based on this repository https://github.com/gluonhq/hello-gluon-ci, the problem I'm having is that it works perfectly in IntelliJ, but when I want to export it to Windows/Android, I encounter the following error

javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/cl/home.fxml:10

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/cl/home.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:935)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:983)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:757)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2853)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2649)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3376)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3332)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3300)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3272)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3248)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3241)
    at cl.MainApp.lambda$init$0(MainApp.java:35)
    at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.util.CachedFactory.get(CachedFactory.java:32)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.doSwitchView(AppManager.java:787)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.switchView(AppManager.java:528)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.switchView(AppManager.java:503)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.continueInit(AppManager.java:324)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.start(AppManager.java:288)
    at cl.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:67)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:169)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST_Runnable_run_16403f8d32adb631126daa893e5e80085c5d6325(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:704)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsPlatformThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsPlatformThreads.java:143)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cl.HomeView
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:52)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188
```

According to what I understand from the error, the FXML is not able to find the controller.

home.fxml

```
<View fx:id="home" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="cl.HomeView">
    <center>
        <StackPane>
            <Button text="Click!" onAction="#onClick"/>
            <Label text="text" fx:id="text"></Label>
        </StackPane>
    </center>
</View>
```

MainApp

```
 appManager.addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, () -> {
            try {
                return (View) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/cl/home.fxml"));

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                ex.printStackTrace(pw);
                String stackTrace = sw.toString();
                System.out.println(stackTrace);
                TextArea textArea = new TextArea(stackTrace);
                textArea.setMinHeight(450);
                return new View(textArea);
            }
        });
```

```
module-info.java

module test {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires com.gluonhq.attach.util;
    requires com.gluonhq.attach.display;
    requires java.datatransfer;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires com.gluonhq.attach.storage;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires java.base;
    requires com.gluonhq.charm.glisten;

    exports cl;

    opens cl to javafx.fxml;

}
```

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc7mq.png)

my git https://github.com/weichafe/Gluon-cli.git

I would like to know if anyone has had the same error or if it has happened to them

Comment: Do you add the controller to the `reflectionList`? Else, do you run `mvn gluonfx:runagent` before doing a build, to discover all possible use of reflection?